# Wanted to achieve DropShadow Effect in UWP Windows 10

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml, windows-10-mobile

My xaml code

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid x:Name="grid" />
        <TextBlock
            x:Name="txtBlock"
            Text="Drop Shadow"
            FontSize="48"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

C# Code behind code

```
private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(this.grid).Compositor;
    var spriteVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    spriteVisual.Size = this.grid.RenderSize.ToVector2();

    var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();  //**Here i am getting exception**
    dropShadow.Mask = this.txtBlock.GetAlphaMask();
    dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(10, 10, 0);
    spriteVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;

    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(this.grid, spriteVisual);
}
```

> I am getting exception of type System.InvalidCastException and inner message is 
>   Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Composition.Compositor' to type 'Windows.UI.Composition.ICompositor2'.
>
> #### Could'nt able to figure out the issue, why this line "var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();" is throwing the exception for me.

Comment: I'm running exactly the code which you provided and it's working completely fine for me and i can observe the drop shadow effect on the textblock content.

Comment: @Manfred can you give some insight onto this issue? When i first started into UWP, i had relative low experience with C# and i also stumbled across these problems when trying to explore the Compositor class.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Srry for posting a incomplete question.

Comment: I tested your code on my side. It also worked well. What's your project's target version and OS version? The [DropShadow Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.dropshadow) is introduced from 14393. Besides, you also could try [DropShadowPanel XAML Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/dropshadowpanel) of [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit), then, you could add dropshadow effect on xaml directly instead of code-behind.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Thanks for the confirmation  but i wanted to achieve the same effect using code behind. Also, for your info. i already tested the same code on machine having **OS build  14393**, it works for me. My only concern is How to compile code on machine having **OS build 10586**

Answer (score 1):

> Also, for your info. i already tested the same code on machine having OS build 14393, it works for me. My only concern is How to compile code on machine having OS build 10586

As I've said, the [DropShadow Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.composition.dropshadow) is introduced from Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (v10.0.14393.0), so it doesn't support in 10586.

As a result, you would need to detect if the APIs are available in current OS before you run the relevant APIs.

Please see this blog [Dynamically detecting features with API contracts (10 by 10)](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/09/15/dynamically-detecting-features-with-api-contracts-10-by-10/#ofBSdV0UyH2VmQtj.97). You could use [ApiInformation Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation) relevant APIs to detect 
the feature.